# What are the disadvantages of AJAX on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ajax-on-rails

what are the scenario's where Ajax could not be used in Rails Application.
Is there any disadvantages of AJAX (AJAX on RAILS) if yes please mention which are they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The browser may not be able to interpret javascript, but rails can detect that and you can act accordingly
- The user cannot back/forward or bookmark a particular state within the page, because it is dynamically generated
- Search engines cannot index particular states within the page

There may be others that i can't think of right now.

Comment: these are general disadvantages of AJAX, not of its Rails' implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I think the biggest disadvantage of AJAX in general is the desire to use is when it is not needed.

Comment: This is true for all programming really. Use the best tool for the job, not necessarily the one you want to use.